# What happened to Grimmson?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, The Ministry of Magic assigned a wizard named Grimmson to hunt down Credence after Newt refused the task.

Later we find out that

> Grimmson was working for Grindelwald

and after informing him that he had carried out

> the assassination of Irma, the Lestrange's old servant

he is tasked with watching over Credence and making sure he comes to no harm.

However, later in the Lestrange tomb, Credence is confronted by

> Yusuf, who is about to kill him,

until Leta tells him that Credence isn't who he's searching for.

If they had arrived at the tomb later, things could have gone very differently. Considering the danger that Credence was in, why wasn't Grimmson there to help?

Comment: FWIW do we know that Grimmson is an Auror? A quick search does nothing to confirm that except the wikia. Pottermore notes him as a bounty hunter in the character reveal - [source](https://www.pottermore.com/news/warner-bros-reveals-the-new-characters-coming-to-the-next-fantastic-beasts-film).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The reference I saw said he was, but after your comment I realized that I don't remember it being confirmed within the film either. I've edited it out just for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## We don't know

The last we see of Grimmson is indeed when he tells Grindelwald that he has killed Irma. Considering that Grimmson will be telling the Ministry he missed it *might* be possible they put someone else on the case but we just don't see them.

> **GRIMMSON** *(shrugging)* He’s sensitive. The Ministry won’t be happy when I tell them I’ve missed. They know my reputation.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 57</sub>

However, we know that Grindelwald did indeed task him with watching over Credence, as you note.

> **GRINDELWALD** Listen to me. The disapproval of cowards is praise to the brave. Your name will be written in glory when wizards rule the world. And the clock is ticking faster. You watch over Credence. Keep him safe. For the greater good.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 57</sub>

We also know that Grimmson must be somewhat good at hiding as he managed to hide in the shadows of the hearing room without Newt knowing he was there.

> *Out of the shadows in the corner comes deep, nasty laughter.*
>
> **GRIMMSON** Same old Scamander.
>
> *NEWT reacts to the sound of the voice. GRIMMSON moves into the light. Scarred, brutal, he is a beast hunter for hire.*
>
> **NEWT** *(furious)* What’s he doing here?
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 19</sub>

He also hides in the wall/camouflages himself in the wall later on when attacking Irma.

> *ANGLE ON THE DARK WALL BEHIND SWATHES OF FABRIC.*
>
> *The perfectly camouflaged GRIMMSON emerges from the wall, raises his wand, aims for the silhouetted figures, and dispatches a Killing Curse that sears through the sheets and clothing, leaving smoldering holes. We hear a body fall. NAGINI screams. CREDENCE’S shadow has vanished.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 56</sub>

Therefore, it is possible that he was at the Lestrange tomb but hiding in the shadows eager not to break his cover until absolutely necessary. Note that Grindelwald is at the tomb, just below it, with all his acolytes so it is entirely possible he was wanting the events above the tomb to play out in his favour. I'm sure he was monitoring the situation, especially considering the door opens only when Grindelwands most favourable outcome is accomplished: Credence still doesn't know who he is and neither do any of them trying to help him.

> **TINA** Leta, do you know who Credence really is? Did you know, when you swapped them?
>
> **LETA** No.
>
> *CREDENCE reacts.*
>
> *An opening suddenly appears in the wall of the mausoleum. All stare at the steps leading down into the earth. The sound of a gigantic crowd rumbles beneath them.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 110</sub>

Considering it was also a trap to get the Aurors to his rally it seems all the more likely that he knew what was happening above and was pretty sure Credence wouldn't be harmed.

> **TINA** It’s a trap.
>
> **NEWT** Yeah. Queenie—the family tree—it’s all been bait.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 111</sub>

Comment: [Unsuccessful bounty hunters](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/6/63/BountyHunters.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160419224708) don't tend to get that much screen time

Answer (score 1):

I just bought the book “Crimes of Grindelwald - The Archive of Magic”, and there it says on page 121 that Grindelwald killed Grimmson!! But it doesn’t appear in the movie. A scene that was left out editing the movie??

Comment: Can you post a scan or picture of the page?

Comment: I'm looking at that page in [this youtube review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACowc9uSCos&t=714s). The writing isn't *especially clear* but it looks like the part about Grimmson says"*"When Grimmson gets too close to Credence, it's the beast hunter who's murdered(?) in his own tracks."*